# Linq query: does this array contain this string?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a better way to do this?

```
    public bool IsServiceRunning(string serviceName)
    {
        string[] services =  client.AllServices();
        return (from s in services
                where s.Equals(serviceName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                select s).Count() > 0;
    }
```

The case insensitivity in the compare is important.

Comment: How that is more clear than a simple foreach loop is beyond me.

Comment: I think the proposed solutions are equally clear to a foreach loop.

Comment: I don't, but to each their own I suppose.

Comment: I believe that foreach is not the same as above because linq statement will be converted to sql that doesn't return each service (because it contains where clause). Using foreach, you return everything (i.e. select *) then you iterate over each record. That is ofc, very different. In this particular example its not important becuase AllServices already selects all records but if it returned query it would not be the same.

Comment: @majkinetor: There is no database involved in this code at all.  Why are you talking about sql?

Comment: @recursive: you can't know that. It depends on what `client` does.

Comment: Well you certainly can't know that there is a database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) linq extension method:

```
public bool IsServiceRunning(string serviceName)
{
    string[] services =  client.AllServices();
    return services.Any(s => 
        s.Equals(serviceName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

This way as soon as a match is found, execution will stop.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
return services.Any(s =>
            s.Equals(serviceName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: @recursive: yep, I saw that horizontal scrollbar and the rest is history :)

Answer (score 4):

A non-LINQ alternative:

```
public bool IsServiceRunning(string serviceName)
{
    string[] services =  client.AllServices();
    return Array.Exists(services,
        s => s.Equals(serviceName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
public bool IsServiceRunning(string serviceName)
{
    string[] services =  client.AllServices();
    foreach( string service in services )
    {
        if( service.Equals( serviceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Really, it is that simple, now get back to work solving *real* problems. ;)

Comment: Ya ya good point but I am interested in learning the language features as well :).